# How to specify extra HTML attributes?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

The ability to add arbitrary HTML attributes to your form elements is pretty basic, but seems to be mostly unavailable in Laravel. It is mentioned in [Laravel's documentation for `Form::label`](http://laravel.com/docs/html#labels) but not for anything else:

I assumed this was just a shortcoming of the documentation, but when I tested this on `Form::select`, I found it does not work there:

```
{{ Form::select('ad_week', $report_list_filters['ad_week'], ['id'=>'ad_week']) }}
```

(I tried again using the older & more verbose syntax for associative arrays, but that didn't help either.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [**official api**](http://laravel.com/api/4.2/) or [**source code**](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/src/Illuminate/Html/FormBuilder.php#L400) for method parameters when the docs aren't clear enough

`select($name, $list, $selected = null, $options)`; select has an extra parameter.

```
{{ Form::select('ad_week', $report_list_filters['ad_week'], '', ['id'=>'ad_week']) }}
```

Comment: Or, if you prefer source: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/src/Illuminate/Html/FormBuilder.php#L400

Comment: Ah, +1 @J.T.Sage the source is much more friendly, added it the answer